# How to call a method from Main Class to another Activity

Tags: java, android, class, methods

I tried this approach:
MainActivity ma=new MainAcivity(), ObtenerModuloActivado,
but it doesn't work...

I have this method in my MainActivity:

```
private void obtenerModulosActivos() {
        ConectWS conectWS = new ConectWS(this, new OnTaskCompleted() {
            @Override
            public void onTaskCompleted(Object feed) {
                setMenuOptions(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTaskError(Object feed) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error en metodo ObtenerModulosA()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        if (oCnn.estaConectado()) {
            mostrarUOcultarLoader(true);
            DatosEvento datosEvento = DatosEvento.obtenerInstancia(getApplicationContext());
            conectWS.execute("ModulosActivos", datosEvento.obtenerIdEvento());
        }
    }
```

And want to call this to another activity:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
///   ----->HERE I WANT TO DECLARE THE METHOD ObtenerModulosActivos();
                ///se agrego esto por rafa
                AgendaGActivity.this.finish();

                break;
            case R.id.menu_busqueda:
                abrirBusqueda();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Don't create new activities manually. If you have shared code, use a separate class with static methods

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Do you want to start another activity? Or do you want to call a method this is in another activity class?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define it public static

```
public static void obtenerModulosActivos()
```

and in another activity

```
MyActivity.obtenerModulosActivos();
```

Comment: I made that, but when I run it, it gives me a error that the method is null

Comment: it's static how it can be possible to be null? it's method definition and it will never be null.